# Retrieving all non empty tables with specific column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm required to get all the tables that are non-empty and hold a specific column name. I saw some tutorials about each of the tasks separately but not combined together, can anyone suggest how to achieve this?

The query for specific column name in the table:

```
Select *
From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
Where COLUMN_NAME like '%company%'
```

And the query for all non-empty tables:

```
SELECT r.table_name, r.row_count, r.[object_id]
FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN (
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(s.[object_id]) table_name, SUM(s.row_count) row_count, s. 
[object_id]
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats s
WHERE s.index_id in (0,1)
GROUP BY s.[object_id]) 
r on t.[object_id] = r.[object_id]
WHERE r.row_count > 0
ORDER BY r.table_name;
```

Any help would be appriciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a join between results to fetch final results.

```
select a11.table_name, a11.row_count, a11.[object_id]
from (SELECT r.table_name, r.row_count, r.[object_id]
FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN (
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(s.[object_id]) table_name, SUM(s.row_count) row_count, s. 
[object_id]
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats s
WHERE s.index_id in (0,1)
GROUP BY s.[object_id]) 
r on t.[object_id] = r.[object_id]
WHERE r.row_count > 0
) a11
join 
(Select table_name
From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
Where COLUMN_NAME like '%company%' 
) a12
on a11.table_name = a12.table_name
order by a11.table_name
```